# How to create a new Scala custom rule in Sonarqube and trigger the same from Sonarqube server?

Tags: scala

**How to implement a Scala Custom rule in Sonarqube and activate the same in Scala Rules in Sonarqube server.**

Comment: Which Scala plugin are you using? The new official Scala plugin? Or [sonar-scala](https://github.com/mwz/sonar-scala)?

Comment: The LTS version of sonarqube i.e. 6.7 and the latest version i.e. 7.6 is using sonar-scala plugin I believe.

Comment: Ok, and what exactly do you mean with custom rule? For example, you can create _"custom"_ rules from the **Scalastyle** templates that `sonar-scala` provides. However, these are not real custom rules, only rules with parameters that you can change. - If you really need to create a new rule, you would need to crate your [custom plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101), the official **Scala** plugin from SonarQube uses a custom meta-language to ease the process of writing rules.

Comment: Hi Luis, my requirement is to create some custom scala rules specific to project. i.e. let's say I don't want to avoid the use of while loop or I would restrict the creation of new objects using new keyword instead i would impose the creation of objects through my custom factory implementation in the scala project etc. So for that I need to write some scala custom rules and trigger same using sonar scala while scanning the project.

Comment: I think the best is that you first check if you can satisfy all your requirements with the already provided rules. For example, **Scalastyle** already provides a rule to disallow the use of `while`. And for the new, you may create a regex that warns every use of the `new` keyword... _(however, if you really want to avoid the use of `new`, I would make the constructor private instead)_. Now, if the rule should work only for a few types, or you have more complex requirements, your only option would be to create a new plugin with your customs rules.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but when I checked the [link]https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Adding+Coding+Rules it says sonar doesn't support custom rules for scala.

Comment: As I said, you have to write your own plugin. You may give a look to the code on the sonar-scala repo. You have to create a rules repository and a sensor. Particularly you may give a look to the **Scalastyle** module on the repo. And check the source code of **Scalastyle** itself to see how to use **Scalariform** to write _rules_. - BTW, if when you are done, you think the rules are common enough to work for many projects, a PR on sonar-scala is always welcome ;) - Anyways, if you have more questions just tag me here.